# Issue installing SDL on Mac

Tags: sdl, macports

I have successfully installed libsdl in the past on my Mac OS X Leopard with macports, but now when I try to do it again (after it was uninstalled a while ago), macports produces this error when attempting to install the dependency "xorg-libXdmcp":

```
Error: org.macports.configure for port xorg-libXdmcp returned: configure failure: command execution failed
Please see the log file for port xorg-libXdmcp for details:
/opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_x11_xorg-libXdmcp/xorg-libXdmcp/main.log
Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
Error: Unable to execute port: upgrade xorg-libXext failed
```

[main.log](http://pastebin.com/D5LH64kK)

EDIT: Okay, this has become a problem with installing xorg-libXdmcp: no matter what I do, it always produces this error. The log says that it couldn't find the xproto package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After attempts to install it via Fink didn't actually seem to *install* it, I just built it from source.